# Using the same app but with differing content

Tags: custom-list

Afternoon,

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

I have created an app called 'Projects' using a custom list.
Following the creation of a page i've inserted this app as a web part two times naming the two lists 'Current' and 'Ongoing'.

The problem I have is when typing content in the 'Current' list it duplicates into the 'Ongoing' list.  I understand that the app i have created is just one instance but how would i use the same app but be able to populate it with different content?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create two apps/lists to hold the different sets of data.

If you want the lists to have the same columns and settings, you could create a [list template](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013/tutorials/content/create-list-template/).

If you need the data to all be in one list, you could connect one of the filter Web Parts (only in SP enterprise I believe) and filter out the data you don't want to be displayed, or create a [view](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9).

Comment: Creating a list template is exactly what i'm trying to achieve here with the same columns  - just different content.  I've made an app from a built-in custom list app.  Then when i save this custom list as a template it saves it in the original place where i started with the built-in custom list app. So i selected this and start creating an new app based on this template and it seems to do exactly the same thing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, you create the list template, choose to add a new app, then _select the template instead of custom list_? You will need to create two instances of it, one to hold each set of data you want to display (unless you choose to filter).

Comment: Specifically, you might want to create a [view](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)